# alert will pop up accordimg to the number of forms i have

Tags: javascript

So I crated a Mad Libs game, and I wanted an alert to pop up when I don't enter anything in the forms, so they know that they need to fill in the blanks to proceed.

[image: Right now the code looks like this]

The popup all comes up at the same time depending on how many forms there are so lets say there are 5 forms, then the pop up will come up 5 times. How would I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code in your question please, not a picture of your code.

Comment: where are you doing the alerting? is it happening in the confirm function? if so that's being called multiple times as you iterate in your loop

Answer (score 0):

You have a "confirm()" statement within a for loop. Every time the for loop iterates, the confirm statement produces a pop up.

Answer (score 0):

remove the alert code from the loop and instead just check if there are blank forms in the loop and if you find one set a value in a var. At the end of the loop if the var indicates you found an empty form.. show the alert then.